# Using LET variable in INCLUDE command in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to organize my SAS code by defining a macro variable called root. Then, I want to be able to have all of my `%INCLUDE` statements use the `&root` value so I can just define the `%INCLUDE` in terms of the root:

```
%LET root = C:\Documents and Settings\me\Desktop\mine\SAS;
%include "&root\lib\work.sas"
```

However, when trying to run this under SAS 9.2 I get the following error from the log:

```
1    %LET root = C:\Documents and Settings\me\Desktop\mine\SAS;
ERROR: Incorrect %INCLUDE statement will not be executed. There is a syntax error.
2    %include "&root\lib\work.sas"
```

So it looks likes the `&root` variable isn't being expanded into its value in the `%INCLUDE` statement. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

## [Edit] Answer

I was missing the `';'` at the end of the `%INCLUDE` statement. =/

Comment: Thanks again to everyone! I'm really happy to see such an active and helpful SAS community here. The problem was, as @Joe pointed out, the missing semi-colon at the end of the INCLUDE (yep, SAS newb here).

Comment: Too Localized: "Fix My Typo." http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186376/191410

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to say i'm a bit confused by your presentation of the error, plus your accepted answer.  In my experience, the `ERROR: Incorrect %INCLUDE statement` would show up after the second line, not before.  Plus, if the macro variable resolution is the issue, then the following is what you'd see:

```
903  %LET root = C:\temp;
904
905  %include "&roots\test.sas";
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference ROOTS not resolved.
WARNING: Physical file does not exist, C:\Users\xxxx\&roots\test.sas.
ERROR: Cannot open %INCLUDE file &roots\test.sas.
```

In your included code, there is no semicolon after the %include.  Is that possibly related to the problem?  When I run the %include then another line that is illegal, for example running them in the opposite order, I do get that error (still after the %include, though).

Comment: Yes Joe it appears you are right.  To recreate that error you need to submit the code with the semicolon missing, submit it a second time, and then submit any valid SAS code.  This will reproduce the error the OP stated.

Comment: Agreed, you are right - I missed that semicolon, which is probably the problem in that case. If you don't mind, I'll also cite that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Joe! You were spot on with the analysis of the error order (the error message occurring before the INCLUDE statement). One of my coworkers pointed it out to me, and since my problem was solved I wanted to give credit for the people that took their time in trying to help me. At the time, @WojtusJ had the most helpful and detailed response, so I tagged it as correct (I didn't know about the '.' variable name delimiter). After further discussion by the community and the correct answer given to the question asked, I have changed my accepted answer to this one. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 4):

In that situation you probably need to use the separator, that marks the end of a macro variable name, which is ".", so your code will look like:

```
%LET root = C:\Documents and Settings\me\Desktop\mine\SAS;
%include "&root.\lib\work.sas"
```

This is actually needed only when variable name "touches" something, but I would recommend using it ALWAYS - it's a good practise. Also when there is a dot after the variable name you should put "that" dot, so there will be two dots, like:

```
%LET root = C:\Documents and Settings\me\Desktop\mine\SAS;
%LET fname = work;
%include "&root.\lib\&fname..sas"
```

**EDIT**

As @Joe correctly states in other answer, the real problem in that situation is a lack of semicolon after **%INCLUDE** statement. Placing it after the path should solve the problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! with any luck I'll get the hang of this SAS stuff yet.

Comment: Good luck, and do not hesitate to share your questions here on Stack. I'll be watching you. ;-)

Comment: Sorry but this is not correct, adding a period is not necessary and will not fix the issue. Please see my response.  Also, IMO, adding a period is only good practice when it is required as it reduces readability.

Comment: @Rob Penridge, you probably missed that the OP accepted this answer as correct, so my solution helped. Also, I never stated that adding a period is NECESSARY, so it looks like you didn't pay enough attention to my answer. As for the practise, when you add period ALWAYS, you do not need to remember when it is necessary, and you can be sure, that other people working with your code doesn't need either. Strange that you didn't catch it in your "many years" practise. What's more, downvoting  correct answer just because it's different than yours simply states that you do not understand SO rules.

Comment: @WojtusJ I marked your solution down because it doesn't solve the problem that the OP stated and would not be useful for future people encountering the same issue.  If you believe otherwise, feel free to adjust your answer to prove it and I will happily upvote it.  Yes the OP did mark your answer as correct but I'm sure it's not the first time on SO  (and it won't be the last) that an incorrect answer has been marked as correct.  You did say that adding the separator is necessary, quoting your answer: "You have to use the separator".

Comment: Well, maybe you are right, although it wasn't my intention, my answer sounds like a dot IS NECESSARY, I'm correcting in, and thanks for sugestion.

Comment: One of my co-workers pointed out the issue, which as @Joe mentioned, was the missing semi-colon (doh!). I marked this as correct because it was, at the time, the most helpful answer, even if it didn't solve my specific issue. I just wanted to make sure to give credit to WojtusJ for a nice response which was also educational for me. Once I get enough rep I'll upvote all of the very helpful and details responses. However, since Joe provided the correct answer (with good analysis of the error output ordering), I respectfully switched my accepted answer to his post.

Comment: I certainly agree with you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have another bug somewhere prior to this statement in your code.  Try restarting SAS and executing just those two lines of code and it should work fine, **it worked just fine for me**:

```
%let root = c:\documents and settings\robert.penridge\desktop\mine\sas;
%include "&root\lib\work.sas";
```

**EDIT**:  This worked for me because I actually added a semicolon.  Realised this after @Joe's correct diagnosis of the problem.

I created the following folder structure on the desktop:

```
\mine\sas\lib
```

And then put work.sas in there with the following contents:

```
%put blah;
```

When I ran the code the results printed `blah` just fine with no error messages.  In fact I have used code just like this across many versions of SAS and across many operating systems for many years.  There's no issue with your code.

Contrary to what some of the other answers suggest here, SAS is smart enough to know that the `\` character can not be part of a macro name so there's no need to explicitly state the end of the macro with the `.` character.

Finally, if you are trying to debug macro code you can also turn on the following options:

```
option mprint mlogic macrogen symbolgen source source2;
```

You can turn them back off like so:

```
option nomprint nomlogic nomacrogen nosymbolgen nosource nosource2;
```

Just be aware that some of these may already be on by default in your SAS environment.

In rare circumstances you may also be running into a macro quoting issue.  This will happen if you have been using macro functions like `%str()` `%bquote()` etc... If this is the case then it can often be resolved by using the `%unquote()` function around the macro variable that is causing issues.  From your code sample it doesn't look like this is the issue but you might have simplified your code for the post.  If this were the case then in your situation the code would be changed to look like this:

```
%let root = c:\documents and settings\robert.penridge\desktop\mine\sas;
%include "%unquote(&root)\lib\work.sas";
```

Comment: Dear Sir, are you 100% sure, that the statement "SAS is smart enough to know that the \ character can not be part of a macro name" is true for all encodings configuration? Is SAS that smart?

Comment: SAS does recognize the end of macro when it is not in A-Za-z0-9_ - that's the default.  I disagree on not using terminating . (I think it helps readability) but I agree that this isn't the specific cause of the error posted above, unless there is something not being said by the OP.